# Setting up Cordova for an Amazon Fire HD 7

Tags: android, cordova, amazon-fire-os

I'm struggling to get my development environment set up for Apache Cordova. I'd like to target an Amazon Fire HD 7 running Fire OS 5.3.6.4 (626532920).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_OS) tells me that:

> The releases are chronologically sorted and categorized based on the underlying version of their Android codebase.

So I'm assuming that this is built on Android 5.1.1 Lollipop?

### Project setup

I first installed Cordova using

```
yarn global add cordova
```

I then generated a new project using

```
cordova create hello_world com.mycompany.hello_world HelloWorld
```

I added Android as the intended platform using

```
cordova platform add android
```

(which installed cordova-android@~7.1.1)

### Requirements

After running  `cordova requirements` I received the following:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: not installed
Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Android SDK: not installed
Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
Android target: not installed
android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Gradle: not installed
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Could not find Android SDK directory.
Might need to install Android SDK or set up 'ANDROID_HOME' env variable.
Some of requirements check failed
```

I resolved (most of) these issues as follows:

#### Java JDK

I installed Java 8 using brew cask (as later versions of Java don't seem to be compatible)

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

#### Android SDK

You first need to create the empty repositories config, otherwise the later steps will fail

```
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```

This then left things looking a lot healthier as far as `cordova requirements` is concerned:

```
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
No android targets (SDKs) installed!
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.10.2/bin/gradle
Some of requirements check failed
```

However I'm struggling with how to set up an Android target for this device.

I think I need to run something like

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```

But I'm not sure which version of Android I should be using. There is a [handy table on the Cordova site](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support) but it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me...